# Symfony Validation Error Message for Missing Required Form Field

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I have a working Form, it has a required field that needs to be notBlank:

```
/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 */
private $field1 = '';
```

If I specify this field in the request, but leave the field empty, I get this response:

```
{
    "code":400,
    "message":"Validation Failed",
    "errors":{
        "children":{
            "field1":{
                "errors":["Field should not be blank"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I omit this field from the request, I get this response:

```
{
    "code":400,
    "message":"Validation Failed",
    "errors":{
        "errors":["Field should not be blank"]
    }
}
```

Is there some built-in Symfony logic somewhere that I can use to make the second example match the first example?

[edit] Was using Symfony 2.5 - now updated to Symfony 2.8.3, same problem.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `NotNull` instead `NotBlank`?

Comment: @walkingRed - Tried that. No dice.

Comment: What's the end goal? You need to identify which field is missing and triggering an error condition?

Comment: The end goal is I want to know why the default behaviour is to attribute generic "field missing" errors at the form level, smells like a bug.

Comment: Have you tried `$buider->add('field1', YourFormType::class, array('error_bubbling' => true))` ?

Comment: "If I omit this field from the request" How did you omit the field ? You would have to remove it from the form object itself. If you are just removing the field from the request object, then symfony throws error

Comment: @Heah - makes no difference. I think `error_bubbling` simply allows the errors to bubble up from the field to the form - not bubble down from the form to the field.

Comment: @pradip - in the first case, the HTTP request body is `{ "field1":"" }` in the second case, the HTTP request body is `{ }` no code is changed between requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior can occur when the field is not presented in the form object itself. In this case violation mapper can't map validation error to one of the fields. Please check that the field is presented in the form object.

Comment: The field is present in the form object, but not present in the POST data. It seems unreasonable to me that if the user omits a required field they should by default be given a completely unhelpful error message.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. But if i remove the field from the form object i got the same result as you described.

Comment: So I now realise I am using the FOSBundle for form and response processing, I am doing some more analysis to find which component isn't behaving.

Comment: So I found that another dev had added an `EventSubscriber` that was removing fields from the form when they were omitted from the request data, in a bid to not override the defaults in the model, instead of just adding default values to the submitted data to allow validation to be applied to the default data. **le sigh**.

Answer (score 0):

You are validating an entity after handling the request. If you pass the entity with empty 'field1' to the validator this object is always not valid. It's looks like a validation error from global level.

Comment: If I choose not to pass a field in the request, the default value is used instead - as in a `HTTP PATCH` request. If the field is not valid, the form should say *which* field is not valid, not just leave you guessing which one is missing.

Comment: Validating over default value should be a success. Validating over empty property throws validation error on property level. Debug '$form->getErrors'. It's look likes an error on global level.

Comment: Debug '$form' object. There will be a target constraint.